# Docker dind : Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

While running `docker:dind` I can't use `docker login` command and any other docker command.

My use case is that I got a Nexus Docker Registry and I'm trying to connect to this registry through GitLab CI.

```
docker run --rm -it docker:stable-dind docker login -u user -p password https://registry.mine.io
```

Give:

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add `--privileged` to command.

`docker run --rm -it --privileged docker:stable-dind docker login -u user -p password https://registry.mine.io`

Comment: Thanks. After I also find out more information about '--privileged' with gitlab-ci. I have to set privileged to true in the configuration file of my runner ~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Comment: Not sure how this answer is marked as correct. Still getting an error with this

`$ docker run -it --rm --privileged --user dockremap docker:stable-dind docker ps
error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.40/containers/json: dial tcp: lookup docker on 194.168.4.100:53: no such host`

Answer (score -2):

I have found solution of same problem in this article
https://www.santoshsrinivas.com/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04/

You need to run next commant on machine with your gitlab-ci worker

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a gitlab-runner docker
sudo service docker restart
```